# FANN: save/load trained ann change MSE?

Tags: neural-network, fann

Such a problem: I've trained some ann using MSE stop function up to "desired error" 10^-5 (5MB of training data, 15000 input items,long training period -- about a day). I've got 0 bit fail during training. I've saved the ann to a file.

Then I loaded the net from the file, and check it on the same training data. And sometimes I'm getting bit fail up to 5 (not so seldom, BTW!).

What is this? Does anybody meet such a phenomenon?

I suspect, this is the rounding artefact: many thousands of weights saved to the file in text format and loaded  back...

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

MSE after fann_reset_MSE() and fann_test_data() has no relation to the error returned by fann_train(). If the ANN is trained up to very low MSE, then fann_get_MSE() and fann_get_bit_fail() are more or less in agreement with values returned by these functions ater fann_reset_MSE() and fann_test_data(). If not (ANN is not trained well), then these values might differ in orders of magnitude.